# Is there a formula to calculate factors of the smallest integer u, for which n, divides a Fibonacci number?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

I have read that a conjecture for Fibonacci entry points, by Paul Bruckman and Peter Anderson has been proven for prime p, that uses the Galois theory and the Chebotarev density theorem to compute the density of primes P, for which m | u.

Is it possible to calculate the distinct prime factors of the index u, for composite n, in any way?

Comment: As far as I know, the easiest way to calculate which Fibonacci numbers are divisible by $n$ is to factor $n$ into prime powers, solve the problem for each prime power, and then combine back again.

Answer (score 0):

Let u<sub>n</sub> be the entry point of n, equal to the LCM of indices, from each entry point of the prime factors of n.  For example, n=26,u<sub>n</sub>=21 because the indices 3, and 7 are the entry points for the prime factors of n, which are 2 and 13.

These methods yield correct results for all known values.
EDIT, this was apparently discovered in D. D. Wall's theorem.

Comment: According to Wikipedia it is unknown whether the following is true for every odd prime p: If F is the least positive Fibonacci number divisible by p then $p^2$ does not divide F.